# Microsoft Reporting Services - how do I calculate the sum of values within a group

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report which has a list that is used to group data by a particlar field (City).

In the list control is a table which has a footer row. In the footer row, the data in the table are summed together using SUM(Field!SalesAmnt.Value).

The problem I have is that the calculated sum values for each group/city are the values for ALL groups/cities - not just for that group/city.

How do I get the report to just sum values within a group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a *group* footer, not a *table* footer. (If you open the group properties window from the group's right-click menu, you'll see checkboxes to include a header and footer there. Not the easiest thing to find if you don't know where to look.)